# How can I output a specific https request argument via python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

When i get a requests from discord server it's send back something like this:

```
{"message": "Unknown Gift Code", "code": 10038}
```

Here my code:

```
import requests

code = str(input("Enter a code: "))
result = requests.get('https://discord.com/api/v8/entitlements/gift-codes/' + str(code) + '?with_application=true&with_subscription_plan=true')
print(result)
```

When I run it, the terminal gives me <Response [404]>, which seems to be the code of the error itself, but I would like the code to output the content of the message argument

I apologize in advance for a possibly stupid question.

Comment: `result.text` and `result.json` depending upon which response you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I can get it myself.
I just use JSON library and do like this:

```
import requests
import json

code = str(input("Enter a code: "))
result = requests.get('https://discord.com/api/v8/entitlements/gift-codes/' + str(code) + '?with_application=true&with_subscription_plan=true')
f_result = json.loads(result.text)
print(f_result)
```